# DotNetOpenAuth / WebSecurity Basic Info Exchange

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth, openid, dotnetopenauth

I've gotten a good number of OAuth logins working on my site now.  My implementation is based on the WebSecurity classes with amends to the code to suit my needs (I pulled the WebSecurity source into mine).

However I'm now facing a new set of problems.  In my application I have opted to make the user email address the login identifier of choice.  It's naturally unique and suits this use case.

However, the OAuth "standards" strikes again.

Some providers will return your email address as "username" (Google) some will return the display name (Facebook).  As it stands I see two options given my particular scenario:

**Option 1**
Pull even more framework source code into my solution until I can chase down where the OpenIdRelyingParty class is actually interacted with (via the DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet facade) and make addition information requests from the OpenID Providers.

**Option 2**
When a user first logs in using an OpenID provider I can display a kind of "complete registration" form that requests missing info based on the provider selected.*

Option 2 is the most immediate and probably the quickest to implement but also includes some code smells through having to do something different based on the provider selected.

Option 1 will take longer but will ultimately make things more future proof.  I will need to perform richer interactions down the line so this also has an edge in that regard.

The more I get into the code it does seem that the WebSecurity class itself is actually very limiting as it hides lots of useful DotNetOpenAuth functionality in the name of making integration easier.

Andrew (the author of DNOA) has said that the Attribute Exchange stuff happens in the OpenIdRelyingParty class but I cannot see from the DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet source code where this class is used so I'm unsure of what source would need to be pulled into my code in order to enable the functionality I need.

Has anyone completely something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AttributeExchange only applies to the OpenID Providers ([Google](https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth/blob/master/src/DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet/Clients/OpenID/GoogleOpenIdClient.cs) and [Yahoo!](https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth/blob/master/src/DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet/Clients/OpenID/YahooOpenIdClient.cs)) and you can see the extension used in their respective source files.

I recommend against using email address as the username. Email addresses can be recycled (an account can expire or be closed/canceled and the email address can be reassigned to a new user). If this happens, your site based on email addresses would "give away" all the data of the old user to the new user. Massive privacy violation and lawsuit potentially happening there. Far better to use the Claimed Identifier for the OpenID cases, or the service provider-specific user id number in the OAuth cases, as the primary identifier in your user table. Certainly you may capture and display the email address everywhere on the web site where you *would* display a username so as far as the user knows that's the username -- it's just that internally you use something more precise than that.

Comment: Hi Andrew, this is in face what I'm doing.  I have 3 tables in the system directly related to identifying people.  UserProfile, Membership and OAuthMembership.  Every member has a profile, local logins use email address, everything else uses the OAuth/OpenID Identifier as the security key for identifying users.  I just wanted to get the Email from OpenID so that the key field in the UserProfile (EMail) could be auto populated.  I've actually added a page for newly registered OpenID/OAuth users to provide this manually now ... thanks!